# mysql 0000-00-00 00:00:00 convert to null

Tags: mysql

In `mysql` `Timestamp`, I want to convert `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to `null`.

first I use, `set sql_safe_updates = 0;`

second I do, `UPDATE TABLE SET FILED = NULL WHERE FILED = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';`

but it also converts the current time like this: `2018-07-31 13:46:00`

what's the problem?

Comment: Check your table definition. The column might not allow nulls and have a default value. Thus when setting to NULL the default is used. Just guessing as I cant see table.

Comment: First I made tabel setting __TIMESTAMP NOT NULL__. how convert null type?

Comment: ALTER TABLE <tablename> MODIFY <columnname> TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL;

Comment: oh!!!Thank you.  It's change null!!

Comment: @최다혜 pls upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your field definition to allow NULL values. Use the following:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> MODIFY <columnname> TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```